# Helm chart not picking up correct values

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to assign static IPs for Load Balancers in GKE to services by storing them in the `values.yaml` file as:

```
ip:
  sandbox:
    service1: xxx.xxx.201.74
    service2: xxx.xxx.80.114
  dev:
    service1: xxx.xxx.249.203
    service2: xxx.xxx.197.77
  test:
    service1: xxx.xxx.123.212
    service2: xxx.xxx.194.133
  prod:
    service1: xxx.xx.244.211
    service2: xxx.xxx.207.177
```

All works fine till I want to deploy to prod and that will fail as:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: template: chart-v1/templates/service2-service.yaml:24:28: executing "chart-v1/templates/service2-service.yaml" at <.Values.ip.prod.service2>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.service2
helm.go:94: [debug] template: chart-v1/templates/service2-service.yaml:24:28: executing "chart-v1/templates/service2-service.yaml" at <.Values.ip.prod.service2>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.service2
```

and the part for `service2-service.yaml` looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    appName: {{ include "common.fullname" . }}
    componentName: service2
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: service2
  name: service2
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "{{ .Values.service.service2.ports.name }}"
    port: {{ .Values.service.service2.ports.port }}
    protocol: {{ .Values.service.service2.ports.protocol }}
    targetPort: {{ .Values.service.service2.ports.port }}
  type: LoadBalancer
{{ if eq .Values.target.deployment.namespace "sandbox" }}
  loadBalancerIP: {{ .Values.ip.sandbox.service2 }}
{{ else if eq .Values.target.deployment.namespace "dev" }}
  loadBalancerIP: {{ .Values.ip.dev.service2 }}
{{ else if eq .Values.target.deployment.namespace "test" }}
  loadBalancerIP: {{ .Values.ip.test.service2 }}
{{ else if eq .Values.target.deployment.namespace "prod" }}
  loadBalancerIP: {{ .Values.ip.prod.service2 }}
{{ else }}
{{ end }}
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: service2
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Any clue why is complaining that is `nil` (empty)?

Comment: working fine with me helm version : v3.9.3, i can not test few scenario however try updating the line `appName: {{ include "common.fullname" $ }}` it could be due to range or value nil pointer in template.

Comment: @HarshManvar still the same problem

Comment: Weird i tested your default Config it’s worked well. However i set static name and remove ports section. So no issue with map you are passing in values.yaml atleast

Comment: @HarshManvar OK, so combination of your suggestion to use `$` and wrapping values as `{{ (.Values.ip.prod).service2 }}` solved my problem. No clue why but it works. You can post it as the solution to my case.

Comment: greattttt..! Glad to hear that issue resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it could be due to the function changing the context and defined in `values.yaml`

Normally with range, we can use the **$** for global scope, `appName: {{ include "common.fullname" $ }}`

When tested the same template by keeping the static value of the **appName** it worked for me, so there is no issue with access from `values.yaml` unless **nil** is getting set at **.Values.ip.prod.service2**.

in other case as you mentioned `{{ (.Values.ip.prod).service2 }}` multiple level nesting will solve issue.